# Carousel is not moving images in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, slider

Hello I am using Visual Studio 2012 Student edition with angualr js 1.4.3 and ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0 to scroll images.

I have applied [`Demo`](http://plnkr.co/edit/1w94wE93nEr1LSU2vQkG?p=preview) code.

The code is working in firefox and IE but not running in chrome (version 52.0.2743.82 m).

For some security issue I can't share my code here so please look at the demo I have provided and demo is running but in my case in my project it's running in all the browser except chrome the code is same. In chrome is stuck after moving to second image and on click event is also not running.

Please someone who knows help to solve this big issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using Version 51.0.2704.106 m and the code works fine for me. There is just a `</div>` tag too much in line 28. **EDIT:** Also works with Version 52.0.2743.82 m

Comment: The carousel is moving and swapping images out fine for me. I'm running Chrome 52.0.2743.82 m. Try updating yours?

Comment: I have updated chrome but after moving to second image it stuck there. version is 52.0.2743.82 m

Comment: I have updated the question please see it. in chrome as per I have given link it scrolls to second image and than stuck not go automatically and on click as well not running.

Comment: "for some security issue I can't share my code" but you provide the link to your project: now all your code is accessible ;)

Comment: As a general rule you should NOT be using jquery selectors when implementing angular.  Please research ng-show/hid/if.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't update to the most recent version of all your third party libraries?  If not - I would advise you update all libs and see if the issue persists.